# Calculate total sum of dates stored in array in rehtinkdb

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript, reql

I have date objects  which are stored in array. I want to calculate sum of all these dates by `rethinkdb` query my data is stored in JSON. The array size can vary.

Comment: How do you define the sum of dates? What is 2017-03-01 + 1998-12-25?

Comment: my  date format is    **Fri Dec 30 2016 10:05:01 GMT+00:00**